# Appium driver - Click function is not working

Tags: appium, appium-android

I have a simple Appium automation test, my code is like this:

```
public class Android {

public static AppiumDriver<AndroidElement> driver;

public AppiumDriver<AndroidElement> setDriver() throws MalformedURLException {

    File appPath= new File("src");
    File app = new File(appPath,"myApp-debug.apk");

    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
    capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "myDevice");
    capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP,app.getAbsolutePath());
    capabilities.setCapability("autoGrantPermissions",true);
    capabilities.setCapability("appWaitActivity","com.xxx.yyy.ui.launch.LaunchActivity");

    driver = new AndroidDriver<AndroidElement>(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"),capabilities);
    return Android.driver;
}
```

And I'm trying to simply click on a link on the first page of the application. here is my code for clicking:

```
public class LaunchPageTest extends Android {
@Test
public void f() throws MalformedURLException {

  //LaunchPageObject lp = new LaunchPageObject(setDriver());
  //lp.Click_SigninNow();

  Android a=new Android();
  a.setDriver().findElement(MobileBy.AndroidUIAutomator("text(\"Sign in now\")")).click();

}
```

The driver opens my application but doesn't click on the link. I don't understand what is wrong!
Thank you in advance

P.S. Here is my Appium log:

```
    [debug] [W3C] Responding to client with driver.createSession() result: {"capabilities":{"platform":"LINUX","webStorageEnabled":false,"takesScreenshot":true,"javascriptEnabled":true,"databaseEnabled":false,"networkConnectionEnabled":true,"locationContextEnabled":false,"warnings":{},"desired":{"platformName":"android","app":"D:\\xxx\\src\\xx-debug.apk","appWaitActivity":"com.yy.xx.ui.launch.LaunchActivity","autoGrantPermissions":true,"deviceName":"myDevice"},"platformName":"android","app":"D:\\xxx\\src\\xx-debug.apk","appWaitActivity":"com.yy.xx.ui.launch.LaunchActivity","autoGrantPermissions":true,"deviceName":"emulator-5554","deviceUDID":"emulator-5554","platformVersion":"9","deviceScreenSize":"1080x1920","deviceModel":"Android SDK built for x86","deviceManufacturer":"Google","appPackage":"com.xx.yy","appWaitPackage":"com.xx.yy","appActivity":"com.yy.xx.xx"}}
[HTTP] <-- POST /wd/hub/session 200 6428 ms - 1010
[HTTP]
[HTTP] --> GET /wd/hub/session/d9a3338e-31e9-44e1-b4f4-fcf540d41ae5
[HTTP] {}
[debug] [W3C] Calling AppiumDriver.getSession() with args: ["d9a3338e-31e9-44e1-b4f4-fcf540d41ae5"]
[debug] [W3C] Responding to client with driver.getSession() result: {"platform":"LINUX","webStorageEnabled":false,"takesScreenshot":true,"javascriptEnabled":true,"databaseEnabled":false,"networkConnectionEnabled":true,"locationContextEnabled":false,"warnings":{},"desired":{"platformName":"android","app":"D:\\xx\\src\\xx-debug.apk","appWaitActivity":"com.yy.xx.ui.launch.LaunchActivity","autoGrantPermissions":true,"deviceName":"myDevice"},"platformName":"android","app":"D:\\xx\\src\\xx-debug.apk","appWaitActivity":"com.yy.xx.ui.launch.LaunchActivity","autoGrantPermissions":true,"deviceName":"emulator-5554","deviceUDID":"emulator-5554","platformVersion":"9","deviceScreenSize":"1080x1920","deviceModel":"Android SDK built for x86","deviceManufacturer":"Google","appPackage":"com.xx.yy","appWaitPackage":"com.xx.yy","appActivity":"com.yy.xx.xx"}
[HTTP] <-- GET /wd/hub/session/d9a3338e-31e9-44e1-b4f4-fcf540d41ae5 200 10 ms - 942
```

Comment: are you sure `MobileBy.AndroidUIAutomator("text(\"Sign in now\")")` is properly written locator?

Comment: yes, I solved the problem with adding commons-lang3-3.7.jar to my referenced libraries

Comment: ok, i was under impression that properly written locator would look like `new UiSelector().text('Sign in now')`

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue by adding **commons-lang3-3.7.jar** to my referenced libraries. It is working fine now.